# Unexpected result from cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, lasso-regression

I would like to perform 10-fold cross validation manually using `prostate data` to learn how to do it manually. I utilise the `elasticnet` package for code. I estimated the parameters by glmnet package (of course, it can perform cross validation too, but I would like to do that manually). After the analysis, It seems to me that I need a different criterion to choose tuning parameter other than minimum of cv.error because this gives the almost null model, if not so "where is my mistake?". (According to the original paper of Tibshirani, optimum model has three variables)

Here is the code

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(glmnet)

x <- scale(prostate[,1:8],T,T)
y <- scale(prostate[,9],T,F)

lambda = seq(0,1,0.02)

cv.folds <- function(n, folds = 10){
  split(sample(1:n), rep(1:folds, length = n))
}

c.val <-  function(x, y, K = 10, lambda, plot.it = TRUE){
    n <- nrow(x)
    all.folds <- cv.folds(length(y), K)
    residmat <- matrix(0, length(lambda), K)
    for(i in seq(K)) {
      omit <- all.folds[[i]]
      xk <- as.matrix(x[-omit, ])
      yk <- as.vector(y[-omit])
      xg <- x[omit, ]
      yg <- y[omit]
      fit <- glmnet(xk, yk, family="gaussian", 
                    alpha=1, lambda=lambda,standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
      fit <- predict(fit,newx=xg,lambda=lambda)
      if(length(omit)==1){fit<-matrix(fit,nrow=1)}
      residmat[, i] <- apply((yg - fit)^2, 2, mean)
    }
    cv <- apply(residmat, 1, mean)
    cv.error <- sqrt(apply(residmat, 1, var)/K)
    object<-list(lambda = lambda, cv = cv, cv.error = cv.error)
    if(plot.it) {
      plot(lambda, cv, type = "b", xlab="lambda", ylim = range(cv, cv + cv.error, cv - cv.error))
    invisible(object)
    }
}

result <- c.val(x,y,K = 10,lambda = lambda)
lambda.opt <- lambda[which.min(result$cv.error)]
fit <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", 
              alpha=1, lambda=lambda.opt,standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
coef(fit)
```

Result:

```
> coef(fit)
9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    s0
(Intercept) .         
lcavol      0.01926724
lweight     .         
age         .         
lbph        .         
svi         .         
lcp         .
```

**Edit:**
Model generated directly from `glmnet`.

```
fit.lasso <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", alpha=1,
                    standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
fit.lasso.cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="mse", alpha=1,
                          family="gaussian",standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
coef.lambda.min <- coef(fit.lasso.cv,s=fit.lasso.cv$lambda.min)
coef.lambda.1se <- coef(fit.lasso.cv,s=fit.lasso.cv$lambda.1se)
cbind(coef.lambda.min,coef.lambda.1se)
```

Result:

```
9 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1         1
(Intercept)  .          .        
lcavol       0.59892674 0.5286355
lweight      0.23669159 0.1201279
age         -0.06979581 .        
lbph         0.09392021 .        
svi          0.24620007 0.1400748
lcp          .          .        
gleason      0.00346421 .        
pgg45        0.06631013 .
```

The second column shows the correct (`lambda.1se`) result.

Comment: When I run your code I get a strange value for the optimal value of lambda (~0.98).

Answer (score 3):

Your "mistake" is very hard to spot: it comes from the fact that `glmnet` will not use the order of your own `lambda` vector to sort the vector of results.

Example with the data you used:

```
res <- glmnet(x, y, lambda=lambda)
res$lambda
```

So when you call the command `lambda[which.min(result$cv.error)]` at the end of your procedure, you will not get the value corresponding to the minimum of the cross-validated error. Also, it explains why your graph looks strange.

An easy fix would be to declare `lambda` at the beginning of the script as a decreasing vector:

```
lambda = seq(1, 0, 0.02)
```

Final remark: be careful when using a single lambda.

Comment: Plus, I think what is called the "optimal value for lambda" is actually not corresponding to the optimal MSE but the "largest value of lambda such that error is within 1 standard error of the minimum."

Comment: I edited the code as you suggest. The result still seems not to correct. I add the code generating the correct model by fully `glmnet`. But, as we can see `lambda.min` generates a model with more variable than the `lambda1se` model as expected from theory.

Comment: I think I see my mistake. the problem stems from definition of `cv` and `cv.error`. Thank you very much for your time.